# Designing for the Cloud

Tags: architecture, cloud

I'm looking to design/code a highly scalable web application. I was going to use the cloud base infrastructure (Amazon EC2) but what I fail to understand is, I need specific users that log on to be directed to a specific VM based on user role.

For instance, I want all users who are 'Managers' to be directed to one VM, all users who are 'Sales' to be directed to another VM. The same application will be deployed to each instance as traffic increases. I wanted the application to use an in-memory database because there will be a lot of write operations that need to be pushed down to all users of that role type.

Comment: So, what is the question here?

Comment: My question is how can I direct users to a specific VM on the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proxy such as [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [HA-Proxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) to route requests based on the URL.

For example, make /manager go to one VM, /sales to another.  If both types of users use the same thing, then I guess you could put the user type in the URL and route accordingly.

Comment: +1: @joe: instead of different URI you may also use different URLs, e.g. sales.myapp.com, mgmt.myapp.com. That way make the different instances independant of each other and there is no need for a proxy (my understanding is that in fact we're talking about different applications).